# how to check if Database is empty swift 3 - Firebase

Tags: swift3, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to create an if statement to check if a database in Firebase is empty or haven't been create it . Any ideas how can I check that ? The app works when I press a button all the data that I have saved will be upload it to the database before I press that button the database is empty.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that you need to check **snapshot children count** first, whether it's empty or not.

**For that** -

```
var ref = Firebase(url: FIREBASE_URL)
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
    if(snapshot.childrenCount > 0){ // It has value already

   }
  else{ // Still Empty 

    // Upload values to firebase

   }
})
```

Hope it will help you to achieve what you want. :)

Comment: I think `if snapshot.exists()` will accomplish the same, and I find it slightly more explicit about its goal. Note that, that this code will download all the data from the database to check if it is empty. There's no way to do this generic a check without that, but it's important to be aware of it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when you add value type listener in firebase like `observeEventType` , snapshot will return you all its children as well as you can also check only snapshot is exist or not. Thanks for updating me. i will dig more into it. :)
By the way I love firebase the way it provides flexibility to its developers like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Amir and Frank , I figure it out. I had to update Amir code a little bit , but I got it to work . Here is the details

```
 let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "DATABASE_PATH")
                            ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot!) in
                                if(snapshot.childrenCount > 0){ // It has value already

                                    print(" value")

                                }
                                else{ // Still Empty 


                                      print("No value")
                                }
                            })
```